# Automated concurrent git push

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull

I'd like to setup one simple repository which would contain output from different projects, compiled on Travis CI.

What I can't figure out is the easiest way how to safely push to the repository from the Travis console. If there are two projects building at the same time and both of them happen to push at the same time, one of them will naturally fail with non-updated refs error.

Since paths in each commit are guaranteed to be unique ([project name]/[commit id]) the best I could come up with is a script like this:

```
while $(git push) not ok {
    git pull --rebase
}
```

Can you think of something better?

Comment: Are you pushing generated artifacts to a git repo?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: yes, that's the idea.

Comment: You **will** need to handle this. Even after that pull, another concurrent job might have started its push and messed up your timeline again. In other words, you will need a slightly smarter script that detects the situation, does the pull and rebase/merge operation and then retries the push, handling the situation yet again if needed.

Comment: Though, if they are completely separate, why not just have one repository per artifact?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: that would require more deploy keys, would be harder to maintain/change etc. Too much hassle for a simple "download current snapshot of each project here" kind of website.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to use `parallel` - as suggested for the general case at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471419/18033

```
parallel --retries 10 --delay 3 ::: "git pull --rebase && git push"
```

`--retries 10` instructs to do 10 retries, `--delay 3` states that 3 seconds should be waited between each retry. Adjust to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to push to two different branches `B1` and `B2`, and have a `post-receive` hook on the server side which will merge those branches to `master`.

Since the paths in each commit are guaranteed to be unique, those merges won't have any conflict and can be automated.

Pushing to two different branches means there should no be any concurrency issue.

Since the remote is GitHub, another approach is to merge those branches on the Travis-CI side, and then push only one branch.

Comment: This would be a cool solution but unfortunately github doesn't allow any custom hooks, only webhooks and for those I need another server to handle them. :-/ I was thinking about letting the branches as they are (i.e. without merging them back to master) but this looked awfully wrong, not to speak about increasing number of branches over the time.

Comment: @MiroKropacek You did not mentioned GitHub ;) I have edited my answer.